# Why does input threshold occur at the unique voltage at which both inverter MOSFETs are in saturation?

Tags: mosfet, cmos, vlsi, device-characteristics

A relevant figure of merit for a CMOS inverter is the so-called input threshold voltage (no relationship to the threshold voltage of a given MOSFET) \$V_{inv}\$, defined as the voltage \$V_{in}\$ at which \$V_{in}=V_{out}\$.

Separately, for analytical MOSFET models which neglect channel length modulation (CLM) (i.e. which neglect the effect of \$V_{ds}\$ on drain current in saturation or, equivalently, which model the MOSFET as a perfect controlled current source in saturation), it follows that there is a unique input voltage (and thus unique output voltage, since an input voltage (I think) determines a unique output voltage) at which both are in saturation.

I have three questions:

(1) Is my claim in the second paragraph above true? If so, why? I can easily prove it for specific analytical models (e.g. the standard square-law model), but I think in the end the relevant consideration is the perfect current source nature of saturation so I'm hoping for a general argument.

(2) From the derivations of \$V_{inv}\$ which I have seen, it seems always assumed that \$V_{inv}\$ occurs when both transistors are in saturation. One then equates the drain currents of both transistors in saturation and solves for the relevant \$V_{in}\$, which we then take as \$V_{inv}\$. It follows from that assumption (and an affirmative answer to (1), above) that \$V_{inv}\$ is that unique voltage at which both transistors are in saturation. Given the definitions above, this is not an a priori equality. Thus, my question is why this is it the case that \$V_{inv}\$ occurs when both transistors are in saturation?

(3) If (2) is true in the case of no CLM, is it also true in the case of CLM? Presumably the DC characteristic of the inverter broadens so that there is a region (nonunique \$V_{in}\$ now) over which both transistors are in saturation. Does \$V_{inv}\$ still happen to be one of those input voltages in which both transistors are in saturation?